# Upgrading to UEFI motherboard while keeping old hard drive

Tags: upgrade, uefi

I want to upgrade my motherboard+CPU, but have no desire to reinstall my Ubuntu system (Ubuntu is the sole OS in the hard drive).  My current MB uses BIOS, but the new one will almost certainly use UEFI.  What should I do before the upgrade to make sure everything will go smoothly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And your new motherboard will almost certainly be able to be put into legacy, BIOS, CSM, etc. mode which ignores the UEFI features.